# how to use the END variable of the CASE statement in WHERE clause of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

let's say I have this query

```
SELECT 
s.name,
s.last_name,
s.created_date,
s.new_flag,
s.enrolled_date

CASE WHEN s.created_date IS NOT NULL AND s.new_flag IS = 0 THEN s.enrolled_date ELSE s.exit_date 
END filter_query
FROM student.s WHERE TO_CHAR(filter_query,'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

this query above says the filter_query column does not exist. how can we make this filter_query work in `TO_CHAR` function ?

Comment: put `,` after `END` and `s.enrolled_date`. then try

Comment: It's not a "variable" - it's a _column_ alias. And it's not a CASE statement, it's a CASE _expression_.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias for an expression like `filter_query` in the `WHERE` condition, since the `WHERE` condition is evaluated *before* the `SELECT` list.

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT name,
       last_name,
       created_date,
       new_flag,
       enrolled_date,
       filter_query
FROM (SELECT s.name,
             s.last_name,
             s.created_date,
             s.new_flag,
             s.enrolled_date,
             CASE WHEN s.created_date IS NOT NULL
                       AND s.new_flag IS = 0
                  THEN s.enrolled_date
                  ELSE s.exit_date 
             END filter_query
      FROM student.s) AS subq
WHERE TO_CHAR(filter_query, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```